# For some reason, a warning is issued when calling the procedure SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('EXPORT to ...')

Tags: db2, export-to-csv

I have the following problem:
I am using the following command:

```
EXPORT TO "D:\ExportFiles\ACTIVATE_DICT.csv" OF DEL MODIFIED BY  TIMESTAMPFORMAT="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS"  STRIPLZEROS MESSAGES "D:\ExportFiles\FMessage.txt" SELECT * FROM DB2INST4.ACTIVATE_DICT;
```

In the Command Editor of the program, the Control Center successfully exported data from the ACTIVATE_DICT table to a CSV file ACTIVATE_DICT.csv.

But for a number of reasons, I need you to execute this command in the IBM Data Studio or DataGrip program, and there it cannot be executed in this form.
Therefore, I read the following manual [enter link description here](http://]https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023573.html)
and based on it wrote the following command:

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('EXPORT to /lotus/ExportFiles/ACTIVATE_DICT.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY TIMESTAMPFORMAT="YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS" STRIPLZEROS MESSAGES /lotus/ExportFiles/FMessage.txt SELECT * FROM DB2INST4.ACTIVATE_DICT');
```

Here is the message on the result of the command:

> [2018-10-11 15:15:23] [     ][3107] There is at least one warning
>   message in the message file.. SQLCODE=3107, SQLSTATE=     ,
>   DRIVER=4.23.42 [2018-10-11 15:15:23] 1 row retrieved starting from 1
>   in 75 ms (execution: 29 ms, fetching: 46 ms)

And in the / lotus / ExportFiles / directory there is no ACTIVATE_DICT.csv file and there is no FMessage.txt file in the / lotus / ExportFiles / directory.

**Question**: How then to correctly execute this command ??? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlcode 3107 is a warning message:
SQL3107W   At least one warning message was encountered during LOAD processing.
Explanation

You can load data into a database from a file, tape, or named pipe using the LOAD command. You can specify that any warnings or errors from the LOAD processing be printed to a message file. If no message file is specified, the warnings or errors are printed to standard out (unless the database manager instance is configured as a partitioned-database environment.)

It is to tell you to read message log in the message file you specified. In your case: /lotus/ExportFiles/FMessage.txt

Please read into the file to see what error is logged and if you need help understand what is logged, please post the content of the file.
This message is returned when at least one warning was received during processing. If a message file is being used, the warnings and errors will be printed there.

This warning does not affect processing.
User response

Review the message file warning.

Comment: These files are not created in the directories specified in the command.

Answer (score 1):

[EXPORT command using the ADMIN_CMD procedure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023573.html)

See use of the 'MESSAGES ON SERVER' clause, and how to get these messages using the result set returned by this routine in this case.

Comment: I have version DB2 8.1.

Comment: I don't have v8.1 docs at hand, but the syntax and use should be the same.
Don't you get the result set mentioned at the link above? Do you get some errors using the 'MESSAGES ON SERVER' option?